# Yii2 или Laravel?

Tags: laravel, php, yii

Что лучше для большого проекта - yii или laravel?

Знаю kohana.

Выбор фреймворка для нового проекта возложено на меня.

После моего старта проект будут дорабатывать другие программисты.

Не хочу ошибиться с выбором.

С каким фреймворком проще будет работать в команде?

Кода будет очень-очень много.

Проект огроменный.

Кэширование, оптимизация на первом плане.

Начал учить yii1. и как-то не нравится, не идет.

Все понимаю, и структуру тоже, но как-то все сложно сделано, или я не прав?

В общем, нужен совет на примере личного опыта.

Времени у меня неделя.

Comment: После того как ``Kohana`` ушла в небытие, я тоже задался вопросом. Но после ``Yii`` остается чувство какой-то неполноценности. ``Laravel`` же очень удобен и понятен. Разница, как между ``NetBeans`` и ``phpStorm``, - в мелочах.   

Никаких аргументов, потому оставляю комментарием. Надо пробовать самому.

Comment: На Laravel пока только два проекта делаю, и нет ни одной причины не рекомендовать его, одни плюсы. С Yii лишь немного разбирался, как и у вас, «не пошло». В общем, субъективный +1 за Laravel.

Comment: Я просто напомню, что Yii2 еще не stable. Выбирайте то, что лучше знаете.

Comment: @fjghkjg, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @fjghkjg, ваша «неделя» на выбор давно прошла. Расскажите, каков выбор, и как идут дела?

Comment: Холивар начнись!

Answer (score 3):

Yii2 уже стабильный http://habrahabr.ru/post/240149/.

Answer (score 3):

Мой выбор пал на Laravel. Очень удобный фреймворк. Я получаю удовольствие, работая с ним.

Comment: Мой выбора пал на Yii2 и Symfony2. Очень удобные фреймворки. Я получаю удовольствие, работая с ними. :)

Comment: Мой выбор пал на ненависть. Очень удобная эмоция. Я испытываю ненависть, работая с Yii, CI, Kohana, Yii2, Opencart, Wordpress, Laravel и прочими невероятными поделками современности.

Answer (score 1):

A Symfony2 вы не рассматриваете? 
Думаю, что лучше всего спросить у программистов, которые будут дорабатывать проект, какой фреймворк им больше подходит.

Answer (score 1):

Неужели Kohana настолько плоха, что просто необходимо писать велосипеды на новом фреймворке? Большие важные проекты пишут на том, что хорошо знают. Если ничего не знаешь - бери модный Laravel, пару лет он будет в тренде.

Answer (score -1):

У меня было невероятно короткое знакомство с Laravel, но он успел надоесть буквально своими объявлениями роутов, отсутствием неймспейсов и бесконечными анонимными функциями и статическими вызовами там, где они не нужны, так что из этих двух я не стал бы и выбирать. "Огроменность", вместе с тем, чуть ли не автоматом банит Yii 1.x и предполагает Symfony или Zend (последний не трогал, но его тоже рекомендуют для больших решений).

> но как то все сложно сделано, или я не прав?

В Yii 1 вообще ни разу не сложно сделано.

Answer (score -1):

Yii2 - Это только для маленьких и средне-маленьких проектов. Он монолитный. И очень плохо расширяемый.

Symfony2 - это только для средних и больших проектов. Хотя сейчас есть режим микроядра. Пока не пробовал.

Laravel 5 - Это для маленьких, средних и средне-больших проектов. Хорошая расширяемость, отличная интуитивность и все совсеменное, что может предложить мир PHP и связанное с ним.

Если вы не планируете приложение крайне огромных масштабов, я бы Выбрал Laravel 5. Он покроет большинство задач. Для остальных его можно расширить. :)

Answer (score -2):

Тут не всё так просто, я сам пишу на kohana (у которой есть свои сюрпризы), потому что он легкий и простой.

Но вместо того чтобы ковырять Laravel или Yii2, возьмите Symfony2, так как это единственный верный вариант для большого проекта, я думаю со мной согласятся многие.

Comment: Не единственный вверный. Есть Zend Framework 2 !